# creating ipa , provision profile not found

Tags: ios, javafx, task, gluon

I'm trying to run task "createIpa" using javafxmobile plugin on gradle but I have this problem:

Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.

> No provisioning profile found matching 'name provision profile'

But the provision profile is correctly installed on my Mac with "name provision profile".
I executed this task many times before this and always worked and I didn't change the certificate and the certificate it isn't expired.

My log:

```
Mac-mini-di-Ws:n_lex wstechsrl$  gradle --info createIpa
Initialized native services in: /private/var/root/.gradle/native
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/3.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
    Starting daemon process: workingDir = /private/var/root/.gradle/daemon/3.1, daemonArgs: [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java, -Xmx4000m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=IT, -Duser.language=it, -Duser.variant, -cp, /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/Denise/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-3.1.jar, org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon, 3.1]
    Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /private/var/root/.gradle/daemon/3.1 Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx4000m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IT -Duser.language=it -Duser.variant -cp /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/Denise/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-3.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 3.1
    Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
    An attempt to start the daemon took 0.731 secs.
    Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=908, address=[43fdf064-6f89-4f7a-be9a-74aa09d6d2ce port:49763, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1501057000195, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6a3b6b01-726d-4fa8-9ccb-a53d80acb178,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/private/var/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=908,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-Xmx4000m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request BuildAndStop{id=c5003605-2bf1-41d7-922d-87695d7c4ef7.1, currentDir=/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex}.
    Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@82ea68c from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=908, address=[43fdf064-6f89-4f7a-be9a-74aa09d6d2ce port:49763, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1501057000195, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6a3b6b01-726d-4fa8-9ccb-a53d80acb178,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/private/var/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=908,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-Xmx4000m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
    The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 908). The daemon log file: /private/var/root/.gradle/daemon/3.1/daemon-908.out.log
    Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
    Executing build with daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6a3b6b01-726d-4fa8-9ccb-a53d80acb178,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/private/var/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=908,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-Xmx4000m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]
    Starting Build
    Settings evaluated using settings file '/master/settings.gradle'.
    Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build.gradle'.
    Included projects: [root project 'n_lex']
    Evaluating root project 'n_lex' using build file '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build.gradle'.
    Android install directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/android
    Android temporary output directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/tmp/android
    Resources directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/tmp/android/resources
    Multi-dex output directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/tmp/android/multi-dex
    Dex output directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/tmp/android/dex
    iOS install directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/ios
    iOS temporary output directory: /Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/build/javafxports/tmp/ios
    Adding dependency for browser in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-browser, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for cache in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-cache, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for connectivity in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-connectivity, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for device in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-device, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for dialer in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-dialer, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for display in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-display, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for lifecycle in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-lifecycle, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for local-notifications in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-local-notifications, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for orientation in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-orientation, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for pictures in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-pictures, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for position in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-position, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for push-notifications in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-push-notifications, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for runtime-args in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-runtime-args, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for settings in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-settings, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for statusbar in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-statusbar, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for storage in configuration compile: {name=charm-down-plugin-storage, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for cache in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-cache-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for display in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-display-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for lifecycle in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-lifecycle-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for runtime-args in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-runtime-args-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for settings in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-settings-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for storage in configuration desktopRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-storage-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for browser in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-browser-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for cache in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-cache-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for connectivity in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-connectivity-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for device in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-device-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for dialer in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-dialer-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for display in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-display-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for lifecycle in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-lifecycle-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for local-notifications in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-local-notifications-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for orientation in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-orientation-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for pictures in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-pictures-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for position in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-position-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for push-notifications in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-push-notifications-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for runtime-args in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-runtime-args-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for settings in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-settings-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for statusbar in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-statusbar-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for storage in configuration iosRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-storage-ios, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for cache in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-cache-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for display in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-display-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for lifecycle in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-lifecycle-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for runtime-args in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-runtime-args-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for settings in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-settings-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    Adding dependency for storage in configuration embeddedRuntime: {name=charm-down-plugin-storage-desktop, version=3.4.0-SNAPSHOT, group=com.gluonhq}
    All projects evaluated.
    Selected primary task 'createIpa' from project :
    Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':createDefaultIOSLauncher', task ':compileIosJava', task ':processIosResources', task ':iosClasses', task ':iosExtractNativeLibs', task ':createIpa']
    Using javafxports version 8.60.9
    Configuring build for iOS
    Using javafxports ios sdk from location /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/ios-sdk/8.60.9/e900bcbcc39096ff9a3a409c28efe35d32f57ef5/unpacked/ios-sdk
    Using robovm sdk from location /private/var/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mobidevelop.robovm/robovm-dist/2.3.0/5628ca14c9057976088ce11fe045c2e1beea9a0b/unpacked/robovm-2.3.0
    :compileJava (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :compileJava
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-browser/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-browser-3.4.0-20170512.143550-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:35:52 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-cache/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-cache-3.4.0-20170512.143631-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:36:32 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-connectivity/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-connectivity-3.4.0-20170512.143806-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:38:08 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-device/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-device-3.4.0-20170512.143847-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:38:48 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-dialer/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-dialer-3.4.0-20170512.143929-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:39:30 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-display/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-display-3.4.0-20170512.144010-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:40:11 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-lifecycle/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-lifecycle-3.4.0-20170512.144101-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:41:03 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-local-notifications/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-local-notifications-3.4.0-20170512.144154-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:41:56 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-orientation/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-orientation-3.4.0-20170512.144314-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:43:15 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-pictures/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-pictures-3.4.0-20170512.144354-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:43:56 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-position/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-position-3.4.0-20170512.144435-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:44:37 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-push-notifications/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-push-notifications-3.4.0-20170512.144516-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:45:18 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-runtime-args/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-runtime-args-3.4.0-20170512.144639-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:46:41 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-settings/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-settings-3.4.0-20170512.144731-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:47:32 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-statusbar/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-statusbar-3.4.0-20170512.144824-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:48:25 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-storage/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-storage-3.4.0-20170512.144905-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:49:06 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-core/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-core-3.4.0-20170512.143213-1.pom is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:32:15 CEST 2017).
    file or directory '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/lib', not found
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-browser/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-browser-3.4.0-20170512.143550-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:35:51 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-cache/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-cache-3.4.0-20170512.143631-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:36:31 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-connectivity/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-connectivity-3.4.0-20170512.143806-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:38:07 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-device/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-device-3.4.0-20170512.143847-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:38:47 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-dialer/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-dialer-3.4.0-20170512.143929-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:39:29 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-display/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-display-3.4.0-20170512.144010-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:40:10 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-lifecycle/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-lifecycle-3.4.0-20170512.144101-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:41:02 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-local-notifications/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-local-notifications-3.4.0-20170512.144154-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:41:54 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-orientation/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-orientation-3.4.0-20170512.144314-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:43:14 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-pictures/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-pictures-3.4.0-20170512.144354-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:43:54 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-position/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-position-3.4.0-20170512.144435-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:44:36 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-push-notifications/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-push-notifications-3.4.0-20170512.144516-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:45:17 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-runtime-args/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-runtime-args-3.4.0-20170512.144639-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:46:39 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-settings/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-settings-3.4.0-20170512.144731-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:47:31 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-statusbar/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-statusbar-3.4.0-20170512.144824-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:48:24 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-plugin-storage/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-plugin-storage-3.4.0-20170512.144905-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:49:05 CEST 2017).
    Cached resource https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/gluonhq/charm-down-core/3.4.0-SNAPSHOT/charm-down-core-3.4.0-20170512.143213-1.jar is up-to-date (lastModified: Fri May 12 16:32:14 CEST 2017).
    Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date (took 11.764 secs).
    :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :compileJava (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 11.774 secs.
    :processResources (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :processResources
    Skipping task ':processResources' as it is up-to-date (took 0.022 secs).
    :processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :processResources (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.025 secs.
    :classes (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :classes
    Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
    :classes UP-TO-DATE
    :classes (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
    :createDefaultIOSLauncher (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :createDefaultIOSLauncher
    Skipping task ':createDefaultIOSLauncher' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).
    :createDefaultIOSLauncher UP-TO-DATE
    :createDefaultIOSLauncher (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
    :compileIosJava (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :compileIosJava
    file or directory '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/lib', not found
    Skipping task ':compileIosJava' as it is up-to-date (took 0.035 secs).
    :compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
    :compileIosJava (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.037 secs.
    :processIosResources (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :processIosResources
    Skipping task ':processIosResources' as it has no source files.
    :processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
    :processIosResources (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
    :iosClasses (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :iosClasses
    Skipping task ':iosClasses' as it has no actions.
    :iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
    :iosClasses (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
    :iosExtractNativeLibs (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :iosExtractNativeLibs
    file or directory '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/lib', not found
    file or directory '/Users/wstechsrl/Desktop/workspace_fx/n_lex/lib', not found
    Skipping task ':iosExtractNativeLibs' as it is up-to-date (took 0.024 secs).
    :iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
    :iosExtractNativeLibs (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.489 secs.
    :createIpa (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
    :createIpa
    Executing task ':createIpa' (up-to-date check took 0.001 secs) due to:
      Task has not declared any outputs.
    :createIpa FAILED
    :createIpa (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.403 secs.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.
    > No provisioning profile found matching 'lex provision profile'

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 18.258 secs
    Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
    Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=908, address=[43fdf064-6f89-4f7a-be9a-74aa09d6d2ce port:49763, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Busy, lastBusy=1501057000195, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=6a3b6b01-726d-4fa8-9ccb-a53d80acb178,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/private/var/root/.gradle/daemon,pid=908,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-Xmx4000m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
    Mac-mini-di-Ws:n_lex wstechsrl$
```

Can anyone help me to solve it? 
Thank you

Comment: Which editor you are using currently...?

Comment: I'm using javafxmobile plugin on Eclipse neon

Comment: Can you describe your settings: jfxmobile plugin version, Xcode version, iOS version, did you install the same app before and suddenly it fails? Can you run `./gradlew --info createIpa` and post the relevant details of the log? Also check the KeyChain app, make sure all your certificates are valid. Run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` and make sure that you have and use a valid identity. Also on Xcode->Preferences->Accounts click on `Download all profiles` for your id, and try again.

Comment: Xcode version: 8.2.1 (but I'm using JavaFX on Eclipse neon), jfxmobile plugin version: 1.3.6, the certificates are all valid. Now I post the log.

Comment: Have you created the IPA for this app before? Have you set the iOS config in the build.gradle file (`apsEnvironment`, `iosProvisioningProfile` and `iosSignIdentity `)? Try to `clean` the project as well before running it the next time.

Comment: yes i created the IPA for this app last week so the IOS config is setted

Comment: If you have done it before, and nothing has changed, the only thing I can think of is that some certificate (there are quite a few) is wrong. Once it happened to me something similar, and I recall going checking every single certificate through the KeyChain app and also on the Apple Developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
1)  Clean your project.

2)  Build your project.

3)  Go to products menu -> select build for -> select Profiling.

4)  In project navigator, find you .app product.

5)  Right click on it and click show in finder.

6)  There you will find folder naming "Release-iphoneos", in this folder you will find your .app extension file.

7)  Create a folder named "Payload", copy that .app file in this folder.

8)  Archive your folder.

9)  After archive, rename your folder to name of your app and change its extension from ".zip" to ".ipa"

10) Your ipa is ready for sharing.
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I'm using javafxmobile plugin on Eclipse